# preg_replace_callback returns duplicate values

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to understand the `preg_replace_callback` function. Inside my callback, I am getting the matched string twice instead of the just one time it appears in the subject string. You can [go here and copy/paste this code](http://phptester.net/) into the tester and see that it returns two values when I would expect one.

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '"\b(http(s)?://\S+)"', 
    function($match){           
        var_dump($match);
        die();
    },
    'http://a'
);
```

The output looks like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "http://a" [1]=> string(8) "http://a" }
```

The [documentation mentions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) returning an array if the subject is an array, or a string otherwise. What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a full pattern match `\b(http(s)?://\S+)` in `$match[0]` and a match for the parenthesized capture group `(http(s)?://\S+)` in `$match[1]`.

In this case just use `$match[0]` something like:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '"\b(http(s)?://\S+)"', 
    function($match){           
        return $match[0] . '/something.php';
    },
    'http://a'
);
```

Replaces `http://a` with `http://a/something.php`.

Comment: Why is it that `s` is not also returned as a parenthesized capture group?

Comment: your subject string doesn't an `s` and you have a `?` making the group optional. If you moved the `?` inside of the parenthesis, the group would always exist, but be blank or `s` depending on whether it is there.

Comment: Oh, I'm swapping between my own code and the example code here. My mistake.